# Is there a reliable way to detect scrolling, on all devices, using javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been struggling with this for a while, and I'm surprised that doing this isn't more straightforward...

I need to detect when the user scrolls a page, either with the mouse, scrollbar or by touch on mobile devices. jQuery has their `scroll()` function which works alright, but it requires that the page is actually scrolling. I want to detect the scrolling wether the page is scrolling or not (say I reach the end of the page, and there is nowhere left to scroll too.. I still want to know if the user is trying to scroll)

I found another question that had asked something similar, along the lines of detecting scroll input even when the page isn't scrolling, and I got this chunk of code:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler(), false);
    document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", MouseWheelHandler(), false);
} else {
    sq.attachEvent("onmousewheel", MouseWheelHandler());
}

function MouseWheelHandler() {
    return function (e) {
        var e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));

        if (delta < 0) {
            // increase scroll amount
        } else {
            // decrease scroll amount
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

At first, this seemed to do the trick, but I'm finding it doesn't really return balanced results with different types of mice, and didn't work too smoothly with touch events, which is the core aspect of this question.

I'm using this in a project that does a lot of fancy events on scroll, with the actual page not actually scrolling at all... But I'm running into the problem of it being incredibly slow with all my standard mice, but incredibly fast on my Apple Magic Mouse. I know that there will naturally be some difference here, as the magic mice do scroll quicker, but the difference is far more off balance than it is between the mice normally.

I'm hoping there is a way to improve upon this to get a more reliable result, with all sorts of different inputs. Any suggestions?

### Edit:

To clarify, in order for an answer to work for me, it needs to work on an element which is *not* scrollable. I have a page which does not scroll at all, but which has other events that fire when the user scrolls. This means that I cannot use properties that are based on the window's scroll position (such as `scrollTop()`).

Comment: For mobile, try falling back to the `touchdown`/`touchmove`/`touchup` events and detect the scroll position with jQuery `scrollTop()`

Comment: `scrollTop()` won't work in my case, where the browser window doesn't actually scroll at all

Comment: `scrollTop()` will work on any scrollable (as in `overflow: scroll;` or `overflow: auto;`) element.

Comment: Yes, and my element is not scrollable, so I cannot use it. I need to detect that there is a scroll input anyways though.

Comment: Then use `$('#thePartInMyElementThatMoves').css('top')`? My point is that you can fall back to touch events to move your "scrolling" element.

Answer (score 0):

You should use window.onscroll most usage and then create a new listener to deal specifically with top and bottom scroll conditions I would suggest using a [mousewheel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/mousewheel) event for desktop browsers and a specifically coded touch responder like below to detect if they are trying to scroll, what direction and if that is possible at the current window.scrollY value.

```
var isOverScroll = function isOverScroll ( touchStartY, touchEndY ) {

    if ( Math.abs( touchStartY - touchEndY ) < 5 ) &&
         ( ( window.scrollY = window.innerHeight && touchStartY - touchEndY > 0 ) ||
           ( window.scrollY = 0                  && touchStartY - touchEndY < 0 ) ) ) {
       return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

There is no way to detect scrollbar events, combine this with your current code and only trigger mouse wheel and touch events if the scrollY position is at either 0 or max.

On a side note if you are trying to get rid of the scroll bar completely that is a very bad idea as it is both a wonderful tool for users as well as something that is a standard part of the ui. If you trying to do a scrollable fullpage app and don't want a scroll bar try using slides. Either way don't continue setting the scroll value thats slow instead just move the whole body using css:

```
 transition: transform3d( 0, YOURSCROLLVALUE , 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is using a plugin for scrolling like

[ISCROLL](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5)

in this example here :

[Example](http://www.coreshifter.com/sandbox/iscroll/examples/pull-to-refresh/)

they use the feature pull to refresh , which will fire upon reaching the maximum scroll available , here by  you can use any custom function (even if your item is not scrollable ).